# How to customize axis labels in a boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

How can I change the labels of the vertical y axis in a boxplot, e.g. from numbers to text?

For example, I would like to replace {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2} with {0hour, 1hours, 2hours, ...}.

Comment: can you pls be bit more detailed? are you using `plot`?

Comment: Just set 'axes=FALSE' when you call '(box)plot' and then set your custom axes with 'axis' (look around the 'at' and 'labels' params).

Comment: i am using:
boxplot(ucenie~hral,names=c("hral","nehral"))    
i get http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?7dc443a69f.jpg
i need to replace -2,-1,0,1,2 with 0hodin,1hodina,etc
then I type:
boxplot(ucenie~hral,names=c("hral","nehral"),axes=FALSE)
> lablist.x=as.vector(c("nehral","hral"))
>lablist.y=as.vector(c("0hodin","0.5=1hodina","1.5-2hodiny","2-3hodiny","nad 3hodiny"))
> axis(1,at=seq(1,2,by=1),labels=FALSE)
> text(x=seq(1,2,by=1),labels=lablist.x,pos=1)
> axis(2,at=seq(1,100,by=25),labels=FALSE)
> text(y=seq(1,100,by=25),lables=lablist.y,pos=2)
but it doen´t work correctly

Answer (score 6):

Here's a reproducible example, that you might adapt to fit with what you want to achieve with your data.

```
opar <- par(las=1)
df <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), x=gl(2, 50, labels=letters[1:2]))
with(df, plot(y ~ x, axes=FALSE))
axis(1, at=1:2, labels=levels(df$x))
axis(2, at=seq(-3, 3, by=1), 
     labels=paste(seq(-3, 3, by=1), "hr", sep=""))
box()
par(opar)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data(cars)
with(cars, boxplot(dist ~ speed))
```

As `speed` was numerical the boxplot has numerical values on the horizontal axis.
Let's create a `character` variable:

```
hours = paste(cars$speed, "hours", sep="")
with(cars, boxplot(dist ~ hours))
```

Now the horizontal axis has text labels.

Comment: (+1) Obviously, this will also work for the y-axis, as requested by the OP :-)

Comment: @chl Thanks, but unfortunately this does not work for the y axis :-(

Comment: Indeed, I wrote too quickly! Maybe you could add a solution where you remove numerical labs on the y-axis and use 'mtext' to add text labels?

Comment: Thank you both, but unfornately it doesnt work in my case